# How to Inherit from ControlCollection in C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms

I have the following code in VB.net and need to convert it to C#...

```vb
Public Class SearchableCollection
    Inherits ControlCollection

    Public Sub New(owner As Control)

    End Sub
End Class
```

When I convert it to c# I get the error "there is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter owner".

```cs
public class SearchableCollection : ControlCollection {
    public SearchableControlCollection(Control owner){

    }
}
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `public SearchableCollection(Control owner){ ... }` ? Not `SearchableControlCollection`

Comment: In vb.net you use MyBase(owner) as a statement but in C# you have to do it in the declaration: public SearchableCollection(Control owner) : base(owner) { ... }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of minor issues with your code:

1. You have named the constructor `SearchableControlCollection`. The name must match the class name `SearchableCollection`.
2. You must pass through the `owner` to the base class constructor for `ControlCollection`.  Add `: base(owner)` to pass the parameter to the parent constructor.

Here is the working code:

```
public class SearchableCollection : ControlCollection
{
    public SearchableCollection(Control owner)
        : base(owner)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest that it would be better to change the name of the class to match the constructor rather than the other way around.  `SearchableControlCollection` is a more appropriate name than just `SearchableCollection`, given that the collection is specifically for controls.

Comment: @jmcilhinney It's a really good point and must admit that I assumed that the OP's class name was as they'd expected

Comment: You're probably right, but the comment was directed more towards the OP than you.  The class name in the C# code matches what they show in the VB code but I think that that was an inappropriate name from the get-go.

Comment: @jmcilhinney the base class includes `Control` in its name but it's being removed in the derived class, while still being specifically a Control collection. For sure `SearchableControlCollection` is a superior name.

Comment: my apologies...I mistyped the constructor name in the SO questjion...it is correct in the original code.  The base(owner) part is what I was forgetting.